# How to get ClientContext in CSR?

Tags: javascript, csom, client-side-rendering

In a document library's `/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, I am trying to render a column from ID to a file URL (`FileLeafRef`).

However this line of code:

```
  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

is giving the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '`get_current`' of undefined

I followed this reference in [stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94797/unable-to-get-property-get-current-of-undefined-or-null-reference) to amend my code. The error no longer show up by rending is not triggered. In below code, CSR_Setup is triggered. However `overrideNameFieldTemplate` and getFileLeafRefbyID is not triggered at all. The Allitems.aspx shows up without error and no change.

What's wrong?

```
(function () {

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CSR_Setup, "SP.js");
function CSR_Setup(){ 
    var overrideNameField = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates.Fields = {
        "InstructionLibID": { "View": overrideNameFieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideNameField); 
}

function overrideNameFieldTemplate(ctx) { 
    var InstructionLibID = ctx.CurrentItem.InstructionLibID;
    var fileRef = getFileLeafRefbyID("Instruction",InstructionLibID);
    if (InstructionLibID) {
        return "<a href='"+ fileRef + "'>Download</a>"; 
    }
    else {
        return "N/A"; 
    }
}

function getFileLeafRefbyID(LibName,Id){        
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
      oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(LibName);

        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(Id);
        clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

        function successHandler() {
            return(oListItem.get_item('FileLeafRef'));
        }

        function errorHandler() {
            console.log('Fail');
        }
}
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure `InstructionLibID` is the internal name of your lookup column?

Comment: Yes. If I remove the line calling "getFileLeafRefbyID". The InstructionLibID column will be rendered correctly.

Comment: Yes. If I remove the line calling "getFileLeafRefbyID" and call Setup_CSR without ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded, the InstructionLibID column will be rendered correctly. Hence I am thinking ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded actually delay my code to AFTER everything render complete?

Comment: You have a ton on undeclared variables in `getFileLeafRefByID` and also you do not have to do `new` on `SP.ClientContext.get_current();`. But none of those things should throw "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined"

Comment: Which variables have problem? Because it doesn't return any error so I may not aware.

Comment: If I run CSR_Setup directly instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CSR_Setup, "SP.js");` I will get the Uncaught type error. If I call `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CSR_Setup, "SP.js")` it will call CSR_Setup without render anything and no error.

Comment: That's probably because the view is done with the rendering when your query is done.  You'll have to populate the values in another way, like give the <a> tags an unique ID you pass to your success method, and set the value there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the content of getFileLeafRefId function in

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {YOUR CODE HERE }
```

I usually wait for "clienttemplates.js" to load for executing my jslink overrides like:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () { OVERRIDE CODE HERE }
```

UPDATE:
Please see below your code changed with the changes I suggested (haven't tested it my self). Give it a try.

```
(function () {
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {

    var overrideNameField = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates.Fields = {
        "InstructionLibID": { "View": overrideNameFieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideNameField); 


    function overrideNameFieldTemplate(ctx) { 
        var InstructionLibID = ctx.CurrentItem.InstructionLibID;
        var fileRef = getFileLeafRefbyID("Instruction",InstructionLibID);
        if (InstructionLibID) {
            return "<a href='"+ fileRef + "'>Download</a>"; 
        }
        else {
            return "N/A"; 
        }
    }

    function getFileLeafRefbyID(LibName,Id){     
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {   
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
            var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(LibName);

            this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(Id);
            clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
                Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));

            function successHandler() {
                return(oListItem.get_item('FileLeafRef'));
            }

            function errorHandler() {
                console.log('Fail');
            }
        });
    }
}); 
})();
```

Comment: Should I placed this code in JSLink or insert in a Content Editor webpart?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use ClientContext with CSR Templating, you have do delay Form-Rendering until everything is loaded. 
You can achieve this by overloading some objects in ClientFormManager:

```
(function () {

    interceptForm();

    //... continue with "normal" CSR templating...


})();

function interceptForm()
{
    var CSIntercept = SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.GetClientForm;

    SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.GetClientForm = function (frmName) {
        frm = CSIntercept(frmName);
        frm.RenderClientFormCS = frm.RenderClientForm;
        frm.RenderClientForm = function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
                frm.RenderClientFormCS();
            }, 'sp.js');
        }
        return frm;
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow, this seems like an excellent solution, nicely done.  Aside from the obvious time that any async calls made using the client context would add, does just waiting for `sp.js` to load add any noticeable delay in the page loading and rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CSR_Setup, "SP.js");`

with

`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CSR_Setup);`

Comment: In my test, both statement exactly return same result, CSR_Setup is triggered but no Template Overrides occur.