# Is it possible to set permission at the column level in a list?

Tags: list, permissions, column, authorization

I built a list that include several columns and I'm trying to restrict editing permissions of certain users to only one column within the list.

I've been able to set permissions only to the entire list or elements.

How can I set permission at the column level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOTB way to handle this. You have to either write a code for it or go for 3rd party tools.

1. Bamboo Solutions offering [Column Level Security](https://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx), You can try it
2. You can write your own code for this. Here is an expample for it.[Part 1](http://blogs.mybridgepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-list-column-level-security-part-1/) [Part2](http://[Part2][2])
3. [Also check this](http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata)

Comment: There are a couple of good hints in there. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 you can *kind of* achieve that through some tricky client side rendering, although it would not be true column level security.

What you would have to do is set up a client side rendering script for the edit form that would:

- Delay rendering until you can check permissions for the current user (already a fairly tricky proposition, although [this technique](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/197447/8992) looks promising)
- If the user has the right permissions, render the field normally with the edit control
- If the user does not have the right permissions, render the field as the default display form rendering (no edit control)

Also, I have never played with client side rendering overrides when the list is in datasheet/quick edit mode, so I can't comment on what's possible there, but obviously you'd have to account for that way of editing as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still on 2010. But we'll be switching over 2016 next year.